# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, nullreferenceexception

If the logic within this method is run from an event handler such as `Button_Click` it works perfectly, but, when running this from a method such as below I get the error:

```
hostView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);
```

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is my code:

```
private void SetupHostTree()
{
    // Set internal host names
    using (var reader = File.OpenText("Configuration.ini"))
    {
        List<string> hostnames = ParseInternalHosts(reader).ToList();
        foreach (string s in hostnames)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(s);
            hostView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);

            string title = s;
            TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
            myTabPage.Name = s;
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the debugger and provide more information about where the error happened.

Comment: He gave all of that information in the question. Read it more carefully.

Comment: @Mike - this type of error shows how exceptions occur. You're reading a config file and it's contents may not be exact. This is most likely not an exceptional circumstance and as such you code defensively - checking for nulls yourself where the content cannot be controlled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are no Selected Nodes :)

Comment: I was just going to say this. I bet the null is hostView.SelectedNode

Comment: Could well be, I assume, when clicking on the button event handler it sets focus on one of the nodes

Answer (score 1):

Probably because no node is currently selected in the `hostView` TreeView.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.selectednode.aspx) says that the `TreeView.SelectedNode` property will return `null` when no node is currently selected. And since you've combined it into an expression, the entire expression is failing because there is no `Nodes` collection on a `null` object!

Try this code:

```
private void SetupHostTree()
{
    // Set internal host names
    using (var reader = File.OpenText("Configuration.ini"))
    {
        List<string> hostnames = ParseInternalHosts(reader).ToList();
        foreach (string s in hostnames)
        {
            // Ensure that a node is currently selected
            TreeNode selectedNode = hostView.SelectedNode;
            if (selectedNode != null)
            {
                TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(s);
                selectedNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);
            }
            else
            {
                // maybe do nothing, or maybe add the new node to the root
            }

            string title = s;
            TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
            myTabPage.Name = s;
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
        }
    }
}
```